# About BCryptedPasswordEncoder in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a problem with BCryptPasswordEncoder in Spring.
If I use SQL Server to store an encrypted password, when I try to log in, I receive a message, the likes of: "Encoded password does not look like BCrypt".

However, when I use MySQL and the same password, I can log in normally.

How I can log in using SQL Server?

Here is the code of class extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, which contain BCryptPasswordEncoder

```
@Autowired
private UserServiceImpl userService;

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Autowired
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/students").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/students/addStudent").hasRole("ADMIN").antMatchers("/students/edit/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/students/{id}").hasRole("ADMIN").anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/students").permitAll().and().logout()
            .invalidateHttpSession(true).clearAuthentication(true)
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .permitAll().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFNcS.png)

Comment: Hi. Can you share the code instead of adding images? It's easier for people to take your code and play around faster instead of writing it from an image down

Comment: Hi @AndreiSfat, i've just add the code which contain BCryptPasswordEncoder. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you are using latest Spring Security 5.x, you need to read a bit the documentation of Spring, because they made some major changes that might be unfamiliar, specifically regarding the [password storage](https://spring.io/blog/2017/11/01/spring-security-5-0-0-rc1-released#password-storage-updated).

You can try changing the `passwordEncoder` bean using the [DelegatingPasswordEncoder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.RC1/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/DelegatingPasswordEncoder.html)

```
@Bean
public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
      return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}
```

As per Spring documentation:

> This change ensures that passwords are now encoded using BCrypt by
>   default, allows for validating passwords in old formats, and allows
>   for upgrading the password storage in the future.

Comment: @TuânPhạm please upvote and accept the answer if it helped you so other people will know what is the fix for this issue